# doing a insert while selecting an specific user

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, import, postgresql-fdw

I'm importing and legacy database to a new database, and changing data format. In this legacy database, I have data as following:

```
Interaction
id: 5458d717cd07870859000004
user_id: 5458d715cd07870859000001
interaction_type: 'like'
```

this is a import of a MongoDB collection to a postgres table.

In the new database, I have the table interaction as following

```
Interaction
id: 1
user_id: 2
interacation_type: 'like'
```

I connected the legacy db to the new db with `postgres_fdw` and I'm importing now, but how can I relate the interaction to the new table user based on old user id? I'm doing `insert into interactions values(x,x,x,x) select (x,x,x,x) from interactions_legacy` but I don't know how to relate the old user from interaction (`5458d717cd07870859000004`) to the new user (`2`). I was thinking in something like

`insert into interactions values (user_id, other_column) select found_new_user(user_id), other_column from legacy_intearctions`. Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you simply add an `old_id` and/or an `old_user_id` columns to the new table?

Comment: I need to relate an interaction to a user, when having in mind that when I import from legacy to db to new db I have a new ID...you got it, right?

Comment: No, possibly not.  You have a `user` table around, right?  It's completely missing from your question how you migrate the data there.  It should, at least in the beginning, act as a map between the old and the new ID, so that you can find all related rows in other tables both via the old and the new ID.